# how to print a large size sprite by as3

Tags: actionscript-3, printing

I've an app in which users first insert some data and then print the data in an aligned and table form. But I have a problem with printing the final document when I print this with a custom class FilePrinter which takes only one non-optional parameter "Sprite". I clearly and rightly follow through the codes but when I print, the printed document is nothing but a clear page. I'm not understanding why this so?
But one thing that should be noted is that the sprite is consisted of an image (with resolution not normal) and the size of printed Document becomes much (Round About 12mb to 15mb) when it is ready to print.
If any one knows about the issue so please help me...
Thanks...!

```
var rslt:MovieClip = new MAIN_DOC();

rslt.box1.text = arr[0].toString();
rslt.box2.text = arr[1].toString();
rslt.box3.text = arr[2].toString();
rslt.box4.text = arr[3].toString();
rslt.box5.text = arr[4].toString();
rslt.box6.text = arr[5].toString();

var BackM:MovieClip = new BackGround();

BackM.PIcont.addChild(picData);

var sprite:Sprite = new Sprite();
sprite.addChild(BackM);
sprite.addChild(rslt);

var print:FilePrinter = new FilePrinter(sprite);
function printBtnClick(e:MouseEvent):void
{
   print.print();
}
```

FilePrinter Class

```
public class FilePrinter { 
    private var pJob:PrintJob;
    private var opt:PrintJobOptions = new PrintJobOptions(true); 
    private var sp:Sprite; 
    public function FilePrinter(sprite:Sprite) { 
        sp = new Sprite(); 
        sp = sprite; 
        pJob = new PrintJob(); 
        if (pJob.start()) 
        { 
            pJob.addPage(sp, null, opt); 
        } 
    } 
    public function startPrint():void { 
        pJob.send(); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Where does `FilePrinter` come from? I cant seem to find its documentation anywhere

Comment: Include the code for this class and where you took the example from, this will help us identify the problem

Comment: I have not taken "FilePrinter" from any where. It is nothing just self made custom Class. This issue remains the same also when I do not use this class but use simple AS3 codes to print.

Comment: I'm sharing Class `FilePrinter` Codes
`package{
 import flash.display.BitmapData;
 import flash.printing.PrintJob;
 import flash.display.Sprite;
 import flash.printing.PrintJobOptions;
 import flash.display.Bitmap;
 public class FilePrinter{
  private var pJob:PrintJob
  private var opt:PrintJobOptions = new PrintJobOptions(true);
  private var sp:Sprite;
  public function FilePrinter(sprite:Sprite) {
   sp = new Sprite();
   sp = sprite;
   pJob = new PrintJob();
   if (pJob.start())
   {
   pJob.addPage(sp, null, opt);
   }
  }
  public function startPrint():void
  {
  pJob.send();
  }
 }
}`

Comment: `FilePrinter` Class is nothing. You should assume that this class has never been used instead simple AS3 codes has been using for print the final document

Comment: ok well if it's not `FilePrinter` that's the issue you need to include more code, like for example what's dispatching `printBtnClick` event?

Comment: Ok, I'm pasting actual codes of `printBtnClick` that I'm using in my document.
`function printBtnClick(J:MouseEvent):void
{
 addChild(sprite);
 var Print:FilePrinter = new FilePrinter(sprite);
        Print.startPrint()
 
}`

Answer (score 1):

From the [Actionscript documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/printing/PrintJob.html):

> Additionally, a 15 second script timeout limit applies to the following intervals:
>
> - PrintJob.start() and the first PrintJob.addPage()
> - PrintJob.addPage() and the next PrintJob.addPage()
> - The last PrintJob.addPage() and PrintJob.send()
>
> If any of the above intervals span more than 15 seconds, the next call to PrintJob.start() on the PrintJob instance returns false, and the next PrintJob.addPage() on the PrintJob instance causes the Flash Player or Adobe AIR to throw a runtime exception.

I'd recommend not initalising your `FilePrinter` class until the button press event triggers, also you seem to be calling `print()` in your button click listener, but there is no such function in your `FilePrinter` class, only `startPrint()`

```
var print:FilePrinter;
function printBtnClick(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    print = new FilePrinter(sprite);
    print.startPrint();
}
```

Comment: This does not matter. I mistakenly have written down `print()`, in my real document I call the `startPrint` function. More Over 15 second limit, I am seeing, not need to apply in this case. Because 15 second time is more and more longer than the actually taken by the flash player. Flash player just takes maximum 3 to 5 second in launching print dialogue box.
Also issue remains the same if `FilePrinter` class initializes after the button press event will trigger.
This is actually problem I'm not understanding, why the printed page is nothing just but a clear page.